# Adding time ago to React Native Elements ListItem

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist, react-native-elements

I used `React Native Elements` `ListItem` to render my items of the `FlatList`. I want to set timeago text (ex: 20 Minutes Ago) in the same line as the title. But when I set the suttitle number of lines to 5, the timeago text comes to subtitle row. How can I fix this?

```
<FlatList
  data={this.props.data}
  renderItem={({item}) => (
    <ListItem
      roundAvatar={true}
      avatar={{uri: item.picture.thumbnail}}
      title={`${item.name.first} ${item.name.last}`}
      titleStyle={styles.title}
      rightTitle="20 Minutes Ago"
      rightTitleStyle={styles.rightTitle}
      rightTitleContainerStyle={styles.rightTitleContainer}
      //  subtitle="This is a sample comment which was commented by the developer."
      subtitleStyle={styles.subtitle}
      subtitleContainerStyle={styles.subtitleContainer}
      subtitleNumberOfLines={5}
      hideChevron={true}
      containerStyle={styles.flatListContainer}
    />
  )}
  keyExtractor={item => item.email}
  ItemSeparatorComponent={this.seperator}
  onRefresh={this.handleRefresh}
  refreshing={this.props.refreshing}
  onEndReached={this.handleLoadMore}
  onEndReachedThreshold={50}
/>
```

Comment: Can you post the `styles` for the `ListItem`, also do you want to set subtitle or not?

Comment: I want to have 5 lines for the subtitle. Subtitle is for the comment.

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1
  },
  listItemContainer: {
    flex: 1,
    borderBottomWidth: 0
  },
  seperator: {
    height: 1,
    width: "86%",
    backgroundColor: "#CED0CE",
    marginLeft: "12%"
  },
  title: {
    marginLeft: 5,
    fontSize: 16,
    fontWeight: "600",
    color: "black"
  },
  subtitle: {
    marginLeft: 5,
    fontSize: 14,
    fontWeight: "normal"
  },
  rightTitle: {
    color: "grey",
    fontSize: 12
  }
});

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **vertical centering** is the *default behaviour* of the [`rightTitle`](https://react-native-training.github.io/react-native-elements/docs/0.19.0/lists.html#righttitle) as the [docs](https://react-native-training.github.io/react-native-elements/docs/0.19.0/lists.html#righttitle) say

> *provide a rightTitle to have a title show up on the right side of the button*

For this you can add the [`rightTitleContainerStyle`](https://react-native-training.github.io/react-native-elements/docs/0.19.0/lists.html#righttitlecontainerstyle) as

```
{position: 'absolute', top: (YOUR_TITLE_FONT_SIZE - YOUR_RIGHT_TITLE_FONT_SIZE) / 2, right: 0}
```

Comment: Thanks very much Pritish. I spent the whole day to fix this.There is one small issue. I want to increase the avatar size. Avatar should be round. But when I increase the size, it becomes square. How can I solve it?

Comment: It would be great if you could post a question for that as well, with the relevant styles for the avatar

Comment: This is the link for the new question Pritish.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49696311/how-to-make-a-round-avatar-with-listitem-of-react-native-elements

Comment: Yes, i've given an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49698356/6606831) to that one.

Comment: It worked as you explained. Thanks Pritish. I asked another question here. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49719835/how-to-get-the-react-native-image-to-fit-to-the-image-width-and-height
Could you please give a hand?

Comment: You might need to add the relevant code for that example.