# How to make a round avatar with ListItem of react-native-elements

Tags: react-native

I want to have a bit bigger avatar for my ListItem of react-native-elements. But when I increase the width and height of the avatar, it becomes square. How can I achieve a rounded avatar with custom width and height of ListItem? This is my code.

How can I resize the avatar and have the round shape?

```
 render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <FlatList
          data={this.props.data}
          renderItem={({ item }) => (
            <ListItem
              roundAvatar={true}
              avatar={{ uri: item.picture.thumbnail }}
              avatarStyle={styles.avatar}
              avatarContainerStyle={styles.avatarContainer}
              title={`${item.name.first} ${item.name.last}`}
              titleStyle={styles.title}
              rightTitle="20 Minutes Ago"
              rightTitleStyle={styles.rightTitle}
              rightTitleContainerStyle={styles.rightTitleContainer}
              subtitle="This was posted by the developer"
              subtitleStyle={styles.subtitle}
              subtitleContainerStyle={styles.subtitleContainer}
              subtitleNumberOfLines={5}
              hideChevron={true}
              containerStyle={styles.listItemContainer}
            />
          )}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1
  },
  listItemContainer: {
    flex: 1,
    borderBottomWidth: 0
  },
  seperator: {
    height: 1,
    width: "86%",
    backgroundColor: "#CED0CE",
    marginLeft: "12%"
  },
  avatar: {
    width: 50,
    height: 50
  },
  title: {
    marginLeft: 5,
    fontSize: 16,
    fontWeight: "600",
    color: "black"
  },
  subtitle: {
    marginLeft: 5,
    fontSize: 14,
    fontWeight: "normal"
  },
  subtitleContainer: {
    marginTop: 0
  }
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the latest stable version docs [**docs**](https://react-native-training.github.io/react-native-elements/docs/0.19.0/lists.html#avatar), the prop [avatar](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/images.html) says that *it can be used as component*.

As mentioned in [index.d.ts](https://github.com/react-native-training/react-native-elements/blob/v0.19.1/src/index.d.ts) file

> avatar?: string | ImageURISource | JSX.Element;

*There are many ways to resolve this issue*, but the convenient way, such that all the elements are **responsive** *would be using **Avatar component** directly from the library*.

```
 <ListItem
                    avatar={<Avatar rounded large source={{uri: 'Your URI'}} height={`YOUR_HEIGHT`} width={`YOUR_WIDTH`}/>}
                    title={`YOUR_TITLE`}
                    titleStyle={styles.title}
                    rightTitle="20 Minutes Ago"
                    rightTitleStyle={styles.rightTitle}
                    rightTitleContainerStyle={styles.rightTitleContainer}
                    subtitle="This was posted by the developer"
                    subtitleStyle={styles.subtitle}
                    subtitleContainerStyle={styles.subtitleContainer}
                    subtitleNumberOfLines={5}
                    hideChevron={true}
                    containerStyle={styles.listItemContainer} />
```

Then you get the liberty to apply the [Avatar](https://react-native-training.github.io/react-native-elements/docs/avatar.html#avatar-props) component's props as per the requirement

*Hope it helps!*

Answer (score 3):

Try modifying the avatar style into :

```
avatar: {
width: 50,
height: 50,
borderRadius: 25,
overflow:'hidden'
}
```

Trick is to make `borderRadius` 50% of width/height. `overflow:hidden` is used to cut down the square to circle. Hope it helps.